# How to read lines from a CSV variable into a multidimensional array in python?

Tags: python, csv, multidimensional-array, python-2.7

The string looks like this:

```
x = '''"High";"10";"Assigned";"2012/06/12 10:11:02"
"Low";"20";"Assigned";"2012/06/12 10:11:02"
"Medium";"30";"Assigned";"2012/06/12 10:11:02"'''
```

I want it to be like this:

```
x = [
[High, 10, Assigned, 2012/06/12 10:11:02],
[Low, 20, Assigned, 2012/06/12 10:11:02],
[Medium, 30, Assigned, 2012/06/12 10:11:02]]
```

Whats the best way to parse this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
>>> import csv
>>> result = [row for row in csv.reader(x.splitlines(), delimiter=';')]
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(result)
[['High', '10', 'Assigned', '2012/06/12 10:11:02'],
 ['Low', '20', 'Assigned', '2012/06/12 10:11:02'],
 ['Medium', '30', 'Assigned', '2012/06/12 10:11:02']]
```

Comment: +1 for use of standard library and the sensitivity to possibility of different csv dialects!

Answer (score 0):

```
out = []
for line in x.splitlines():
    out.append( line.split(';') )
```

Or, in one line:

```
out = [line.split(';') for line in x.splitlines()]
```

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner using [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[line.split(';') for line in x.replace('"','').split('\n')]
```

gives:

```
[['High', '10', 'Assigned', '2012/06/12 10:11:02'],
 ['Low', '20', 'Assigned', '2012/06/12 10:11:02'],
 ['Medium', '30', 'Assigned', '2012/06/12 10:11:02']]
```

and also gets rid of `"` in result leaving only the single quotes `'`