# Splitting values out of a CSV Reader Python

Tags: python, list, csv, split

Here is my current code

```
a_reader = None
a_reader     = open('data.csv', 'rU')
a_csv_reader = csv.reader(a_reader)

for row in a_csv_reader:
       print row
a_reader.close()

count = 0
sum   = 0.0
a_reader     = open('data.csv', 'rU')
a_csv_reader = csv.reader(a_reader)
a_csv_reader.next()

for row in a_csv_reader:
        if count != 0 and row[0] != '':
            sum = sum + float(row[0])
        count = count + 1

a_reader.close()
print 'Number of lines is:',count
print 'Sum is:',sum
return listStation
```

This produces the results below

```
['1', '476050', '7709929']    
['2', '473971', '7707713']    
['3', '465676', '7691097']    
['4', '515612', '7702192']    
['5', '516655', '7704405']    
['6', '519788', '7713255']    
['7', '538466', '7683341']    
Number of lines is: 8    
Sum is: 28.0
```

Ok now what I want to do is to split out the value of the ID, Easting and Northing and append them to a list to create one 2d list. Is it possible to do this? If so can you provide me the code?

Comment: By a 2d list, do you mean a list of lists containing just ID, Easting and Northing?

Comment: @yanhan yes thats it just containing the values for ID, Easting and Northing. I.e dl= [[1,476050,7709920],[2,473971,7707713]] and so on is that clearer?

Comment: Have you tried `list.append()` yet?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams no how would I apply the list.append() method? Please

Comment: [Holy bleeping bleeping bleeping bleeping bleepity bleep...](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

Comment: Derrr Im overthinking things again

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read lines from a CSV variable into a multidimensional array in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998413/how-to-read-lines-from-a-csv-variable-into-a-multidimensional-array-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

```
rows = []
for row in a_csv_reader:
       rows.append(row)
```

Will yield in `rows`:

```
[['1', '476050', '7709929']    
['2', '473971', '7707713']    
['3', '465676', '7691097']    
['4', '515612', '7702192']    
['5', '516655', '7704405']    
['6', '519788', '7713255']    
['7', '538466', '7683341']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import csv

def run():
    count = 0
    sum = 0.0
    listStation = []
    with open('data.csv', 'rU') as a_reader:
        a_csv_reader = csv.reader(a_reader)
        for row in a_csv_reader:
            if count != 0:
                if row[0] != '':
                    sum = sum + float(row[0])
                listStation.append(map(int, row))
            print 'row =', row
            count = count + 1
    print 'Number of lines is:',count
    print 'Sum is:', sum
    print listStation

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your `data.csv` file, to test with, but here's how I'd rewrite your code and make it produce the 2D list you want:

```
import csv

with open('test_data.csv', 'rU') as a_reader:
    a_csv_reader = csv.reader(a_reader)

    for row in a_csv_reader:
        print row

with open('test_data.csv', 'rU') as a_reader:
    a_csv_reader = csv.reader(a_reader)
    a_csv_reader.next()

    listStation = []
    count = 0
    total = 0.0
    for row in a_csv_reader:
        if count != 0 and row[0] != '':
            total += float(row[0])
        count += 1
        listStation.append(map(int, row))

print 'Number of lines is:', count
print 'Sum is:', total
print 'listStation:', listStation
```

Output:

```
['ID', 'Easting', 'Northing']
['1', '476050', '7709929']
['2', '473971', '7707713']
['3', '465676', '7691097']
['4', '515612', '7702192']
['5', '516655', '7704405']
['6', '519788', '7713255']
['7', '538466', '7683341']
Number of lines is: 7
Sum is: 27.0
listStation: [[1, 476050, 7709929], [2, 473971, 7707713], [3, 465676, 7691097], 
              [4, 515612, 7702192], [5, 516655, 7704405], [6, 519788, 7713255], 
              [7, 538466, 7683341]]
```

Note, I changed the variable you named `sum` to `total` to prevent a conflict with the built-in [`sum()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=sum#sum) function.

Answer (score 0):

The following might work (depends on the data though - do blank first columns/otherwise invalid numbers exist in the columns etc...):

```
from itertools import islice
import csv

with open('data.csv') as fin:
    csvin = islice(csv.reader(fin), 1, None) # skip header
    rows = [map(int, row) for row in csvin]

print 'Rows are:'
print rows
print 'Number of lines is:', len(stuff)
print 'Sum is:', sum(row[0] for row in stuff)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose I would write your code with a DictReader and default dict:

```
import csv

data={}
with open('/tmp/sta.txt','r') as fin:
    reader=csv.DictReader(fin)
    for row in reader:
        for k,v in row.items():
            data.setdefault(k,[]).append(float(v))

print data
print 'Sum is:',sum(data['Station ID'])
print 'Number of lines is:',len(data['Station ID'])+1
```

Prints:

```
{'Station ID': [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0], 
 'Easting': [476050.0, 473971.0, 465676.0, 515612.0, 516655.0, 519788.0, 538466.0],
 'Northing': [7709929.0, 7707713.0, 7691097.0, 7702192.0, 7704405.0, 7713255.0, 7683341.0]}
Sum is: 28.0
Number of lines is: 8
```