# Extracting a CSV table into list (python 2.7)

Tags: python, database, python-2.7

I have the following CSV of Data in a file called data.csv

```
Inc,Time (seconds),Distance (Miles),cost,,,,,
1,37.7,0.12,7,,,,,
2,31.3,0.02,9,,,,,
3,36,0.13,9,,,,,
4,32.1,0.02,9,,,,,
```

(It's more more than just these 5 lines. Its about 60 rows)

I need to put this data into Python and effectively create a list of all the Inc Vales, Time Values, Distance Vales and Cost Values.

Then later on I will do data analyse such as add all the time values together etc. (that i'm fine on).

I need to just split this data up into 4 different variable lists.

If any one could point me in the correct direction or show me a few lines of code that can simple do this, that would be really appreciated.

I'm starting this code with:

```
dat_file = open("data.csv", 'r')
data = my_file.read()
```

Cheers

Comment: See http://goo.gl/ZWoiXp

Comment: Paulo I wish I could +1000 your brilliant comment. You made my day!

Comment: lol, doesn't help unfortunately. I'm trying to figure out how to take the list of data, split it up into individual variables on the column.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the Python "csv" module.  It seems the have the capabilities to read the data into rows and columns.  The following link gives some good info and examples:
http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/systems-programming/using-the-csv-module-in-python/

Answer (score 0):

Try starting with a dictionary:

```
import csv

data={}
with open('/tmp/sta.txt','r') as fin:
    reader=csv.DictReader(fin)
    for row in reader:
        for k,v in row.items():
            data.setdefault(k,[]).append(float(v))

print data
```

[Splitting values out of a CSV Reader Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17247824/splitting-values-out-of-a-csv-reader-python)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this:

```
import csv

data={}
Inc = []
Time = []
Dist = []
Cost = []

f = open("test.csv")
reader=csv.DictReader(f)

for dict in reader:
    Inc.append(dict["Inc"])
    Time.append(dict["Time (seconds)"])
    Dist.append(dict["Distance (Miles)"])
    Cost.append(dict["cost"])
```

Which gives what you wanted - a collection of lists.

```
In [43]: Inc
Out[43]: ['1', '1', '2', '3', '4']

In [44]: Time
Out[44]: ['37.7', '31.3', '36', '32.1']

In [45]: Cost
Out[45]: ['7', '9', '9', '9']

In [46]: Dist
Out[46]: ['0.12', '0.02', '0.13', '0.02']
```